# Limit systemd service memory for docker

Tags: systemd

I've got a very wierd problem with `docker.service`. I try to limit memory using that `MemoryLimit=8G`but when I do that containers won't to start after service restart. Other limitatnions which I use works fine:

```
CPUWeight=60
CPUQuota=80%
IOWeight=20
MemorySwapMax=1
```

Some details:

```
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b7f0
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:25:46 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b7f0
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:24:19 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

system: Ubuntu 18 LTS (5.0.0-1032-azure)